how can i move player in camera direction
I need to move character in the camera view direction in Unity3d, in game I have a 3rd person camera.
Moving script:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody player;
    public float speed = 5f;
    private Vector3 moveVector;
    void Awake()
    {
        player = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        moveVector.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        moveVector.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        player.MovePosition(player.position + moveVector * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}

Camera script:
using UnityEngine;

public class FPCameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _sensivity;
    [SerializeField] private Transform _player;
    [SerializeField] private float _verticalLover;
    [SerializeField] private float _verticalUpper;
    private float _currentVerticalAngle;

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var vertical = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * _sensivity * Time.deltaTime;
        var horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * _sensivity * Time.deltaTime;

        _currentVerticalAngle = Mathf.Clamp(_currentVerticalAngle + vertical, _verticalUpper, _verticalLover);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(_currentVerticalAngle, 0, 0);

        _player.Rotate(0, horizontal, 0);
    }
}

I tried a lot of material about it, switched many of moving and cameras scripts but nothing works

Have a look on this forum entry.
Here’s how you can modify your Update method in the movePlayer script:
Please double-check, I am currently unable to test.
movePlayer.cs
void Update()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 moveDirection = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0, moveVertical);
    moveDirection = Camera.main.transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
    moveDirection.y = 0.0f;

    player.MovePosition(player.position + moveDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}


If your game character is a 3rd person:
in the character script


using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static CharacterController  instance; //singleton
    public static CharacterController  Instance
    {
         get
         {
            if (instance  != null)
               return instance;
          }
     }

    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public Vector3 MovementDirection; //Here I entered the coordinates where the character will constantly move.
 
     private void Start()
     {
          instance = this;
      }

    private void Update()
    {

        Vector3 difference = transform.position - MovementDirection;
        difference.y = 0; //Here we calculate the difference between the character's own position and the target position, and this turns into a kind of "direction" data, and when we normalize it, we obtain a coordinate where the character can go at a recurring and regular speed.

        Vector3 movement = difference.normalized * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime; //Here we multiply this direction by the speed and determine the speed of the character.

        transform.Translate(movement); or rigidBody.veloctiy(movement * "characterSpeed"); (character speed is just a value you need to write it yourself);
    }
}



In the camera script:


using UnityEngine;

public class RaycastFromCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Camera mainCamera;
    public float raycastDistance = 100f; //It is actually good that this value is high, because a direct raycast goes in the direction it looks from the screen, and this raycast must be as long as possible, otherwise it may not hit the collider of the ground object considered "ground".

    public LayerMask groundLayer; // add terrain or ground layer mask here;

    private void Start()
    {
        mainCamera = Camera.main;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Ray ray = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2f, Screen.height / 2f, 0f)); //We are establishing the structure of the ray to be sent from the screen.
        RaycastHit hit;  // ray's hit data.

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, raycastDistance, groundLayer)) //We send ray from the screen;
        {

            GameObject hitObject = hit.collider.gameObject; //the object which ray hit.

            
            if (hitObject != null) // iIf the ray does not got to the empty space.
            {
                CharacterController.Instance.MovementDirection = hit.point;  //Here we took the point where the ray touched and converted it into the direction data of the character.
            }
        }
        else
        {
            
        }



The character always moves towards the point where the camera is looking... This is more or less done this way, I don't know if there may be errors in the codes, but you can adapt this to your own project. You can think of this as a pseudo code.

using UnityEngine;

public class MoveTowards : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speedOfMovement = 6f;
    private Camera main_camera;

    void Start()
    {
        main_camera = Camera.main;
    }

    float GetHorizontalInput()
    { 
        return Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); 
    }

    float GetVerticlalInput()
    { 
        return Input.GetAxis("Vertical"); 
    }
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 forwardMovement = main_camera.transform.forward;
        Vector3 rightMovement = main_camera.transform.right;
        forwardMovement.y = 0f;
        rightMovement.y = 0f;
        forwardMovement.Normalize();
        rightMovement.Normalize();

        Vector3 movementDirection = (forwardMovement * GetVerticlalInput() + 
        rightMovement * GetHorizontalInput()).normalized;
        transform.position += movementDirection * speedOfMovement * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}


Thank you for posting this answer. While this code may answer the question, might you please [edit] your post to add an explanation as to why/how it works? This can help future readers learn and apply your answer. You are also more likely to get positive feedback (upvotes) when you include an explanation.
